# How do I connect my iPhone to my local docker container if they're both on the same network?

Tags: docker

I am trying to connect my iPhone to my api hosted on an instance created on my macbook.  They are both on the same network.

Comment: You could add some more information to your question. Are you using Docker Machine? How was the container launched (`docker run` command)? Can you connect to the API container from your Mac already? What troubleshooting have you done already?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running docker on linux, then you need to expose ports (`docker run -p xxx:xx`) so it can be accessed by someone outside the host but within the network.

If you are running docker on mac, then you can configure your VM in bridge mode and do the same. Alternatively, you can setup your VM to forward ports so it reaches Docker.

Comment: Can you post the steps to achieve configuring the VM in bridge mode for the mac?

Comment: This would be a question for serverfault :)